# Highstock chart tooltip activation only when inside the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to enforce that the tooltip show up only when mouse pointer is inside the chart area and not when on navigator scrollbar or on time range selectors in the top?

http://jsfiddle.net/1p4f5kny/

```
/*
The purpose of this demo is to demonstrate how multiple charts on the same page can be linked
through DOM and Highcharts events and API methods. It takes a standard Highcharts config with a
small variation for each data set, and a mouse/touch event handler to bind the charts together.
*/

$(function () {

    /**
     * In order to synchronize tooltips and crosshairs, override the
     * built-in events with handlers defined on the parent element.
     */
    $('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
        var chart,
            point,
            i,
            event;

        for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
            chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
            event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); // Find coordinates within the chart
            point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true); // Get the hovered point

            if (point) {
                point.highlight(e);
            }
        }
    });
    /**
     * Override the reset function, we don't need to hide the tooltips and crosshairs.
     */
    Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function () {
        return undefined;
    };

    /**
     * Highlight a point by showing tooltip, setting hover state and draw crosshair
     */
    Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function (event) {
        this.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
        this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip
        this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); // Show the crosshair
    };

    /**
     * Synchronize zooming through the setExtremes event handler.
     */
    function syncExtremes(e) {
        var thisChart = this.chart;

        if (e.trigger !== 'syncExtremes') { // Prevent feedback loop
            Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function (chart) {
                if (chart !== thisChart) {
                    if (chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes) { // It is null while updating
                        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, undefined, false, { trigger: 'syncExtremes' });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Get the data. The contents of the data file can be viewed at
    // https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/activity.json
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=activity.json&callback=?', function (activity) {
        $.each(activity.datasets, function (i, dataset) {

            // Add X values
            /*dataset.data = Highcharts.map(dataset.data, function (val, j) {
                return [activity.xData[j], val];
            });*/

            $('<div class="chart">')
                .appendTo('#container')
                .highcharts('StockChart', {
                    chart: {
                        marginLeft: 40, // Keep all charts left aligned
                        spacingTop: 20,
                        spacingBottom: 20
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: dataset.name,
                        align: 'left',
                        margin: 0,
                        x: 30
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        crosshair: true,
                        events: {
                            setExtremes: syncExtremes
                        },
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value} km'
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        positioner: function () {
                            return {
                                x: this.chart.chartWidth - this.label.width, // right aligned
                                y: -1 // align to title
                            };
                        },
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        backgroundColor: 'none',
                        pointFormat: '{point.y}',
                        headerFormat: '',
                        shadow: false,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '18px'
                        },
                        shared: false,
                        valueDecimals: dataset.valueDecimals
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: dataset.data,
                        name: dataset.name,
                        type: dataset.type,
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
                        fillOpacity: 0.3,
                        tooltip: {
                            valueSuffix: ' ' + dataset.unit
                        }
                    }]
                });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of binding events on the container, you can use point `mouseOver` event to synchronize tooltips:

```
series: [{
    point: {
        events: {
            mouseOver: function(e) {
                for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
                    chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
                    if (chart !== this.series.chart) {
                        point = chart.series[0].points[this.index];
                        chart.tooltip.refresh([point]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g0brx52d/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events.mouseOver

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you @ppotaczek